# How do install Ubuntu on VMware Player and have it visible and usable by all users?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Host OS is Windows 7. VMware Player 5 will host the virtual machine. Ubuntu desktop is the virtual OS

How can I install and configure VMware Player and Ubuntu so all users can login and use the Ubuntu VM?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ms-Windows related question.

1) You must create the virtual machine and install it Ubuntu
2) the "VM files" must be in a shared folder for every Windows user
3) you can make the vmdk file to launch de VMWare player, so any user can start it

Are you really sure if WUBI isnt your best option?? you can have a better performance

Comment: Just because it just **involves** Windows, it doesn't mean is off-topic. And the OP wants VMware with Ubuntu. Not Wubi.